# Is there's a way use SELECT as an expression of CASE WHEN?

Tags: sqlite

I'm new in SQLite and I would like to ask if there's a way use SELECT as expression of CASE WHEN?

e.g.

```
CASE WHEN item_type = 'item' THEN 
    SELECT * FROM items ... END AS 'col_1', 
        WHEN item_type = 'subitem' THEN 
            SELECT * FROM subitems ... END AS 'col_2'
```

Comment: You can't use `CASE` like that. Give some example tables, and what you would like as output, and we might be able to find concise SQL syntax for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. All you need to do is to enclose your sub-selects in parentheses. For example, this works:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 0 THEN (SELECT 1) ELSE (SELECT 0) END
```

Also, sub-select must return exactly single value (it cannot return more than 1 value). So, if you tried to `SELECT * FROM subitems ...`, it would NOT work, unless table `subitems` contained only one column and single row in it.